# AWS security group for inbound traffic

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have two AWS Linux AMI servers.
One with a Node.JS HTTPS server and the second running my Mongo DB.

The only way to connect to my Mongo DB server is through my Node.JS server.

In my in the AWS security group for the Mongo DB server I was able to put the name of the the AWS security group for the Node.JS server in the 'Source' column in the 'Inbound' tab and it allowed connectivity, but I'm wondering what setting the security group actually does?

More specifically, what IP addresses is this allowing?

[image]

If you click the 'i' next to Source it states:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I initially resorted to using the "private IP address" for communication between AWS instances because according to [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html),

> A private IP address is an IP address that's not reachable over the
>   Internet. You can use private IP addresses for communication between
>   instances in the same network (EC2-Classic or a VPC).

But after some discussion (see comments below) it seems the better solution may be to utilize  AWS Security Groups. My initially hesitation in using AWS security groups was unfounded.

My fear was that if I added the same security group assigned to my Node.js server to the 'Source' for the inbound traffic tab of my MongoDB server, then my MongoDB server would inherit the same inbound traffic rules (all traffic).

The aforementioned fear is unfounded because setting the inbound source to a security group does NOT inherit the rules, but rather simply allows inbound traffic from any instance that has been assigned to that security group.

Comment: I think you are going about this backwards. The preferred way to do this is by designating security groups (as you were originally doing), not IP addresses. Using IP addresses will not work well with things like autoscaling.

Comment: Well, yes, this works too, but you're definitely wrong to say this is the "proper" solution, because the way you had it before was equally proper.  When you set a security group id as the source, you are allowing any instance in that security group to be matched.  The VPC infrastructure knows which instances are members of which groups, so this approach is perfectly valid and much simpler to maintain as you scale up. Specifying a security group is exactly equivalent to adding the private IP addresses of members of the group individually, except that there's no need to manage the addresses.

Comment: @MarkB you type faster than me, apparently.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot yeah but you said it better than I did.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot what if that security group that I use for my node.js server allows all inbound traffic?  If I assign the same security group to my MongoDB server, then would that mean the mongo DB would allow all inbound traffic too?

Comment: @MarkB  I'll ask you the same question I asked Michael. what if that security group that I use for my node.js server allows all inbound traffic? If I assign the same security group to my MongoDB server, then would that mean the mongo DB would allow all inbound traffic too?

Comment: Oh, I see what you were thinking, but no... the *rules* in the other group are unimportant. The other group could even have no rules at all. Using a group as the source means traffic is allowed from the *instances* that are members of the referenced group.  Nothing to do with the *rules* in the referenced group.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thank you for the response. That clears up my confusion regarding setting the security group in the source. If you want, please submit an answer to my question and I'll mark it as answered.